# Not able to click a button using WebDriver in Java

Tags: java, extjs, xpath, selenium, webdriver

I need to click on the save button after filling some text fields. The problem is the xpath keeps on changing every time I reload the page, the id is dynamic. Please help me in clicking this button in WebDriver. Is it possible to click using the text of the button ?
Here is the firebug out-put.
[image]

Please help how to generate a target to click this button.

```
</div>
<div class="x-window-bl">
<div class="x-window-br">
<div class="x-window-bc">
<div id="ext-gen427" class="x-window-footer">
<div class="x-panel-btns-ct" id="ext-gen503">
<div id="ext-gen496" class="x-panel-btns x-panel-btns-right">
<table cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="ext-gen430" class="x-panel-btn-td dms_bluebtn dms_smallbtn">
<table id="ext-comp-1039" class="x-btn-wrap x-btn " cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"     border="0" style="width: 75px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="x-btn-left" id="ext-gen537">
<i>&nbsp;</i>
</td>
<td id="ext-gen498" class="x-btn-center">
<em unselectable="on">
<button id="ext-gen432" class="x-btn-text" type="button">Save</button>
</em>
</td>
<td class="x-btn-right">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td id="ext-gen438" class="x-panel-btn-td dms_greybtn dms_smallbtn">
<table id="ext-comp-1040" class="x-btn-wrap x-btn " cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"         border="0" style="width: 75px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="x-btn-left">
<i id="ext-gen562">&nbsp;</i>
</td>
<td id="ext-gen513" class="x-btn-center">
<em unselectable="on">
<button id="ext-gen440" class="x-btn-text" type="button">Cancel</button>
</em>
</td>
<td class="x-btn-right" id="ext-gen548">
<i>&nbsp;</i>
```

Comment: You need to teach yourself the different ways you can use xpath to identify an element - I recommend the [W3C XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/). It's also worth learning about the other identifying methods in webdriver e.g. identifying by css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use XPath. Assuming you have only one button name Save on this page you can do:

```
By.xpath("//button[text() = 'Save']")
```

Comment: I would recommend against using XPath to select an element by its text. Its not always reliable (especially in IE). I would instead recommend the above suggested comments to use XPath (or better yet, CSS) to select the element via IDs, classes, tags.

Comment: @bgoad Sure, it is easier and more realiable to use IDs. But as the question states, there is no reliable ID and judging from the HTML snippet it pretty much looks like dynamically generated source code. Sometimes there is just no other way. I would be interested to see any bugs or reports about XPath errors in IE - I have never encountered any so far (which does not mean they do not exist...). I  disagree about prefering selection based on css over XPath - In my opinions CSS changes frequently in the development process and XPath queries can be more stable and easier maintainable.

Comment: there is no native XPath library for IE (like there is for the other browsers). Instead, WebDriver injects an old third-party library when using IE that is quite slow, and has been known to be unreliable at times. http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/XpathInWebDriver and do a google search for "webdriver ie xpath" and notice all the flakey issues. Interestingly enough, as far as your last statement goes, I feel the exact same way, only in reverse. If xpath had native support in IE, it would really just come down to preference.